# How do you take user input in a separate method?

Tags: java, methods, user-input

In my method "move" I am printing out instructions to the user.  In the method "game" I need to take the user input and make the program do different things depending on the user input by using the method "usersMove". I originally had my user input scanned in the method "move" but that method has to stay as a void. Is there a way to take the user input in the "game" method so that I can apply its value to other methods?

```
public static void move()
    {
        System.out.print("What do you want to do?");
    }

public static void usersMove(String playerName, int gesture)
{
    int userMove = game(); 

    if (userMove == -1)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void game()
{
    move();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userMove = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: *Why* does move() have to remain void ?

Comment: Its is only suppose to print out a question and nothing else. I had it working fine before that I found out it should have no return value and take no input.

Comment: @user2181402 : dude i think this is your 3rd or 4th question in the same code snippet , i would suggest you to plz go n study how to create a method in java , and what does return type of a metho means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using static methods like this is really bad practice for "real" programs, but I'm assuming this is a Java learning exercise... Just keep in mind, if you're doing it like this in future, you're probably doing it wrong.

Make `userMove` static, like the methods are:

```
private static int userMove = -2; // or whatever value to indicate there's no move
```

Then just use it in static methods of same class:

```
public static void usersMove(String playerName, int gesture)
{
    // just for fun, to catch bugs
    if (userMove < -1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("illegal userMove value " + userMove);
    }

    if (userMove == -1)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void game()
{
    move();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    userMove = scan.nextInt();
}
```

---

Read for example [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to learn about `static` in Java.

Comment: So I declare this within the class but outside of any of the methods I have?

Comment: @user2181402 Yes, then it becomes static member variable of that *class*, meaning there will be just one of them, shared with all instances of the class, and also accessible even if there are no instances created.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I am very new to java and still learning.

Comment: @user2181402 Note: there's nothing stopping you from making the `scan` static too, and you may in fact *need* to do that to avoid chars being lost to buffering (not sure, but if you seem to lose user input, try that).

Answer (score 0):

Make the scanner `scan` static, while keeping the initialization within `game()`, then use it wherever you need a value.